# How do I re-use reports on different datasets?

Tags: mysql, database-design, reporting-services, reporting, birt

What is the best way to re-use reports on different tables / datasets?

I have a number of reports built in BIRT, which get their data from a flat (un-normalized) MySQL table, the data which in turn has been imported from an excel sheet.

In BIRT, I've constructed my query like this, such that I can change the field names and re-use the report:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT index as "Index", name as "Name", param1 as "First Parameter" FROM mytable) t
```

However, then when I switch to a new client's data, I need to change the query to the new data source and this doesn't seem sustainable or anywhere near a good practice.

So... *what is a good practice?*

- Is this a reporting issue, or a database-design issue?
- Do I create a standard view that the report connects to?
- If I have a standard view, do I create a different view with the same structure for each data table, or keep replacing the view with a reference to the correct data table each time I run the report?

What's annoying is the excel sheets keep changing - new columns are added, and different clients name their data differently.  Even if I can standardize this, I'd store different client data in different tables... so would I need to create a different report for each client, or pass in the table name to the report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways and the path you choose is really dictated by how much flexibility you have architecturally.

First, you are on the right track by renaming your selected columns to a common name since that name is what is used to bind the data to the control on the report.  Have you considered a stored procedure to access the data?  This removes the query from the report and allows you to set up the stored proc on any database to return the necessary columns.  If you cannot off-load to a stored proc, you can always rely on altering the query text at run-time.  Because BIRT reports are not compiled (they are XML) you can change the query based on parameters and have it executed for each run of the design.  Look at the `onCreate` event for the Data Set and you can access `this.queryText` and do any dynamic string substitution you need via JavaScript.  Hidden parameters are a good way to help alter/tune the query. If you build the Data Set correctly, the changing of the underlying data could be as easy as changing the Data Source and then re-associating the Data Set to the new Data Source (in the edit data set window).  I have done this MANY times and it works well.  If you are going down this route, I would add the Data Source(s), Data Set(s) and any controls that they provide data to a report library.  With the library you can use the controls in many reports and maintain them in one spot.  If you update the library, all the reports using the library get updated as well.

Alternatively, if you want to really commit to a fully re-usable strategy that allows you to build a library of reusable components you could check out the free Reusable Component Library at BIRT Exchange ([Reusable Component Library](http://www.birt-exchange.com/be/marketplace/app-showcase/?app=25)).  In my opinion this strategy would give you the re-use you are looking for but at the expense of maintainability.  It is abstraction to the point of obfuscation.  It requires totally generic names for columns and controls that make debugging very difficult.  While it would not be my first choice (the option above would be) others have used it successfully so I thought I would include it here since it directly speaks to your question.

Comment: Thanks! I think renaming the columns is the easiest, and then creating a standard view that all datasets will have, at least until there is a more structured environment.  Then, I can simply pass in the view name as a report variable, and I don't need to change the report.